Cholesky decomposition forward stability analysis
Assume I have a relatively well-conditioned PSD matrix $A$, and I do the Cholesky decomposition of it as $$A = LDL^T$$
where the diagonal elements of $L$ are $1$, and $D$ is a PSD diagonal matrix. If I am calculating this using floating-point arithmetic, and end up with $\hat{L}$, is it possible to prove a forward stability result like
$$\frac{\|L-\hat{L}\|}{\|L\|}<C\epsilon\cdot\kappa(A),$$
where $\epsilon$ is the machine precision, and $\kappa(A)$ is the condition number of $A$?
I saw this result on page 9 of these slides without proof or reference.
(ps. There are well-known results of backward stability such as $\hat{L}\hat{L}^T = A+O(\epsilon \|A\|)$, and forward and backward stability results for solving linear systems using Cholesky decomposition. However, these seem cannot to be applied directly to the current question concerning the forward stability of the factorization itself.)

I realized that a perturbation analysis is enough to establish the forward stability given the backward stability. To be specific, we may first state the well-known result that $$\hat{L}\hat{L}^T=A+E$$ such that $\|E\|< C\epsilon\|A\|$.
We can then exploit the result of Sun:
$$\frac{\|L-\hat{L}\|_F}{\|L\|_p} \leq \sqrt{2 }  \cdot \frac{\kappa_2(A)\|E\|_F /\|A\|_p}{1+\sqrt{ \left(1-2 \kappa_2(A)\|E\|_F /\|A\|_2\right)}}, \quad p=2, F.$$
